# How to split each element of the RDD in spark with python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Now I have a RDD which has sentences as its element.How to use map() and split() to split every sentence by spaces and make the every single word to be the element of the RDD instead of the list returned by split()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use flatMap() to get each word in RDD so you will get RDD[String]. try it as below

```
val rdd=sc.textFile(filePath)
rdd.flatMap(line=>line.split(" "))
```

Above code is for scala please write corresponding code in python.